# Install under-development extension over web-store version

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I would like to test/debug storage migration of an extension. When installing via "Load unpacked" a new ID is generated and the extension is installed as a separate extension.

How can it be installed as an upgrade of the previously installed extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy published esxtension's key:

1. Copy your extension url.
2. Paste into [crx-viewer](https://robwu.nl/crxviewer/) and click on **open in viewer**
3. Open console and copy public key
4. Add this line in your manifest.json

   {
   "key":"you_copied_key"
   }